# CPU usage spikes play framework java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

backend application is developed in play framework.
connects to 2 different databases mysql and oracle.

After 2 to 3 hours the CPU consumption spikes to 100%.

I could not find the exact root cause for the same issue as the issue has come after 6 months of deployment. However in windows event viewer i found the following errors for MYsql

WindowsEventViewer log

> Aborted connection 472 to db: 'mydb' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.

Logs found in WINSERVER.err of mysql

> 2019-12-18T05:07:35.110436Z 472 [Note] Aborted connection 472 to db:
>   'mydb' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing
>   communication packets)

I am creating a db connection at the start of the application which is used throughout the application.

my db configuration

> db.mydb.hikaricp.minimumIdle=2 db.mydb.hikaricp.maximumPoolSize=4
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.idleTimeout=600000       #### 10 mins
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.maxLifetime=1800000      #### 30 mins
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.cachePrepStmts=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.prepStmtCacheSize=250
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.useServerPrepStmts=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.useLocalSessionState=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.cacheServerConfiguration=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.elideSetAutoCommits=true
>   db.mydb.hikaricp.maintainTimeStats=false

Comment: try to read this https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/

Answer (score 1):

## I think you have a memory leak.

Yes I know, this is not a good news: your application creates objects that cannot delete because are referentiated by other objects so the heap going full and the garbage collector began to run more frequently without successufull remove nothing ... so high GC activity generally has negative effect on CPU usage.

### Thesis verification

You have several ways to test your memory usage  and they are different depending on whether the problem is occurring or not.

#### The problem is on going

If you can access to your production environment via ssh, you can run the following command (as super user):

`jstat -gc <pid java> 15000 10`

Obtaining something like this:

[image]

In this manner you are taking 10 samples on the last 15 seconds of your garbage collector activity; if the FGC (the number of Full Garage Collection events from the startup of jvm) frequency is 1 per second or something like this you have a memory leak! Remember, usualy for 10 YGC (Young Garbage Collection: a lightweight  version of gc) runs you have only 1 FGC (this numbers are meant to be indicative only).

Alternatively, if you can have in the production environmnet a monitor of the heap (VisualVM or similar tool)

In this case you can have a graph like this:

[image]

you can have an heap dump and analyze it verifying the most present objects.

#### The problem is not occurring yet

Again, using an heap monitor (VisualVM) you can use for a while your application and then force a run of the Full Garbage Collector and verify that the number of your own objects (objects of your application)  is significantly reduced or zeroed at each passage.

Answer (score 0):

High CPU in MySQL is usually cured by having a better index and/or reformulating queries.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) for turning on the slowlog and providing information on the query/queries to fix.

Comment: High CPU consumption is happening in my java process that is connected to mysql. However I will check for indexes.

Comment: I have truncated most of the data in my tables and started my application. Still the same scenario.

Comment: @Cloy - Look for tools to find where Java is spending most of its time.